# how to call and pass array data to layout from controller in zend 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-layout

Here is my Code, how to and pass data from controller to layout

```
   $arr = array();
   $arr['layout'] = 'example';
   $this->layout()->calllayout = $arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$this->layout()->setVariable('var', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before ViewModel Write serVariable by $this->layout() like:

```
$arr = array();
$arr['layout'] = 'example';
$this->layout()->setVariable('variableName', $arr);
```

and Access it like :

```
echo $this->variableName['layout'];
```